Is it correct that the strong brother rather than the weak brother is the one condemned in Romans 14:23?
I first saw this interpretation from the following source where he talked about the greek work diakrino and its usages in the New Testament: David DeGraaf "Some Doubts About Doubt..." Journal of the Evangelical Theological Society, 2005
I want to ask if this argument is correct, or at least more accurate than how this text is usually understood, or if it is misunderstanding the text.
To quote DeGraaf,

"Most translations of verse 23 are similar to the NASB: 'But he who doubts is condemned if he eats, because his eating is not from faith. . . .' In these versions the translators view Paul's focus as having shifted from the 'strong' person who can eat anything to the 'weak' person who has scruples but eats anyway. However, there is no indication in the context that any of the 'weak' have been induced to eat what the 'strong' are eating. The problem Paul is addresing in the passage is not that people are violating their own scruples, but that people are allowing their differing opinions about a permissible diet to divide the community. It seems likely that the strong people–those without dietary scruples–are contributing to rifts in the body of Christ because they continue to insist on exercising their dietary freedom even though the weak people feel that they cannot associate with people who do." ~ David DeGraaf, pg 740-741

If you look at Romans 14:1, the word diakrisis is present, and it seems to me that Paul wants them to welcome weaker brothers without diakrisis in a sense. In Romans 14:23, the one who does diakrino is condemned. If the stronger brother is directed not to do that in Romans 14:1, and the one who does it is condemned in Romans 14:23, is it reasonable that the one who does it in Romans 14:23 is the stronger brother (the same kind of person Paul is telling not to do it in Romans 14:1?)? DeGraaf argued that Paul in Romans 14:1 is telling the stronger brother to accept the weak without being divisive over secondary issues. Basically, the context is the difficulty of the gathering together of strong and weak believers and how they are dividing over secondary issues (like what to eat) when they should be more unified around their faith.
Notice what Paul said in Romans 14:19.

"So then let us pursue what makes for peace and for mutual upbuilding." (Romans 14:19, ESV)

Paul doesn’t want them to be divisive over comparatively silly matters like food choices or holy days when they should be unified as a body.
DeGraaf argued that translating the opening of Romans 14:23 instead as “the divisive person” would be more reasonable with the context of the passage. Hence, the divisive stronger brother would be the one condemned in Romans 14:23?
Romans 14:16 says this:

"So do not let what you regard as good be spoken of as evil" (Romans 14:16, ESV)

Is it right that this would happen if the stronger brother, who regards the food rightly as good, were to be divisive in his consumption of it and his enjoyment of the freedom he has in Christ, and therefore his liberty in Christ to enjoy good food would be spoken of as evil?
And you have the proceeding verses right before Romans 14:23. Are these texts seem to in reference to the stronger believer being careful to be sensitive towards the weaker brother, so as to not cause him to stumble?

"Do not, for the sake of food, destroy the work of God. Everything is indeed clean, but it is wrong for anyone to make another stumble by what he eats. It is good not to eat meat or drink wine or do anything that causes your brother to stumble. The faith that you have, keep between yourself and God. Blessed is the one who has no reason to pass judgment on himself for what he approves." (Romans 14:20-22, ESV)

Next is Romans 14:23—

"But whoever has doubts is condemned if he eats, because the eating is not from faith. For whatever does not proceed from faith is sin." (Romans 14:23, ESV).

This is the text this question is mainly based on.
DeGraaf argued,

"If the instance of διακρίνω in this passage were rendered 'the divisive person' ... the person in focus in verse 23 will still be the strong person who is in focus in verse 22. The argument in verses 22 and 23 will be essentially a restatement of the argument in verse 20: eat what you want, but do not undermine your brother's faith in doing so. If you do, you are condemned, not for violating your own conscience, but rather for acting in a way not in keeping with πίστις." ~ David Degraaf, pg 741

Basically, his argument is that the person in reference in Romans 14:23 is the stronger brother, not the weaker brother. In terms of what it means to not eat out of faith in context then, DeGraaf argued that to not eat in faith would be in a communal sense. It would be to deny the obligation to be loving to the weaker brother and sensitive to his conviction about what to eat. See Romans 14:15 and Romans 14:20.
To add another piece that seems to make this argument even stronger, DeGraaf also mentioned,

"It means to set aside one's personal freedom for the sake of others and the unity of the body. Furthermore, it is precisely this theme that is expanded in the first part of Romans 15." ~ David Degraaf, pg 741.

Notice the first two verses of Romans 15, which is important since Romans 14:23 is the last verse of what is as chapter 14, and there were no original chapter and verse markers, meaning this text follows right after Romans 14:23.

“We who are strong have an obligation to bear with the failings of the weak, and not to please ourselves. Let each of us please his neighbor for his good, to build him up.” (Romans 15:1-2, ESV).

Rather than the strong being insensitive, they should be sensitive towards the weaker brothers.
Again, does it make sense that in light of the surrounding context, that the one who Paul instructs not to do the diakrisis in Romans 14:1 is the kind of person who may do the diakrino in Romans 14:23 and is condemned, behaving in a divisive way?

This whole section of scripture from verse 13 to 23, is about not stumbling a brother regarding what to eat, and what not to eat. This is about maintaining a clear conscience before God in such matters. It is about individual consciences. The emphasis is on a strong conscience which is that of the mature Christian who understands such matters. This stands in contrast to the new Christian who has not yet come to understand the matter. Their conscience is said to be 'weak' in so far as they have not matured in matters of faith.
This eating is to be a matter of faith, as the text states in Romans 14:23. Everything a Christian does is to be done 'in faith', governed by faith, because of faith, and that is evidence of a strong, godly conscience. They understand what it means to avoid certain things, and when it is permissible not to avoid them. That is why the apostle says they have no need to enquire as to whether a certain meat has been properly drained of blood, or whether it has been offered to an idol first, in the meat market. This is confirmed in Acts chapter 15. But the new Christian does not have a strong enough conscience to yet go along with that. Their conscience would trouble them, whereas the mature Christian who knows they do not need to make such enquiries, retains a clear conscience.
So, the answer is, No, this is not about the strong brother being condemned nor is it about the weak brother being condemned. If the weak one goes ahead and eats just because others do that, his conscience condemns him, but nobody else is condemning him. He or she must be settled in their own mind and conscience, before God, that what they do - or choose not to do - is based on faith. All of Acts chapter 15 needs to be studied as it related directly to Romans 14 - the whole chapter - about not stumbling those who have a weak conscience. Mature Christians will be held accountable for stumbling their fellows who don't have as mature a conscience, who are weaker in the faith. But being held accountable is not the same as "being condemned."
The weak is not to be condemned (in conscience) by the strength of the strong.
The strong is not to be weakened by the weakness of the weak.
All are to have faith. And to love one another.

Excellent balance and an astute weighing up of the question. Up-voted +1.

Yes, the "strong" brother is the one that Paul is telling, "Do not destroy the work of God for the sake of food".
Many seem to be missing the fundamental meaning of this chapter:

The expression "weak in the faith" refers to someone that has recently converted or is considering converting, the weakness being in their knowledge and understanding, not in the strength of their personal faith.
These proselytes are non-Jewish Romans, many of whom are ascetics or vegetarians ("eateth herbs").
The people that are "strong" in the faith already know that it is okay to eat (clean) meat.

What Paul is concerned about is that the proselytes are seeing Christians eating animal flesh, and perhaps being almost forced to eat meat themselves.
This is an act they instinctively abhor, and as a result they will not be in a state to properly receive the real meaning of being a Christian, and will give up and fall away.
Christians are allowed to eat lamb for instance, but they are not required to do so.
With time these proselytes will eventually understand and accept that the restrictions of their previous life were unnecessary.
Yet some of the long-standing members of the church are making an important issue out of this rather than concentrating on teaching the fundamentals of the Gospel.
For a fuller description, see my answer to Romans 14:23 should it be translated "whatever is not of faith is sin" or "sin is whatever not of faith"?

Paul isn't addressing "proselytes".  Proselytes were brought into the "Jews' religion" (Gal 1:11-16).  Paul is addressing new Gentile believing members of the church, the body of Christ. Romans 11:13
"For I speak to you Gentiles, inasmuch as I am the apostle of the Gentiles, I magnify mine office:"

@MarkVestal says "new Gentile believing members of the church". Exactly. define:proselyte - Google Search: "a person who has converted from one opinion, religion, or party to another.".  They are in the process of converting to Christianity from Asceticism etc., people that believe in self-deprivation and shunning physical pleasure.  The Book of Romans was written several years after the Jerusalem Conference, which decided that conversion to Judaism is not required for pagan converts to Christianity.

Understood. I thought you were referring specifically to those who entered the Jewish religion. I believe Paul actually speaks to everyone during the transition from Israel's rise to their fall. Thanks for the clarification, sorry for the confusion. Acts 13:43 "Now when the congregation was broken up, many of the Jews and religious proselytes followed Paul and Barnabas: who, speaking to them, persuaded them to continue in the grace of God."

There's a bit of irony going on in Romans 14, and Paul uses that to focus attention on what really matters.
Romans 14:1 sets the topic (NASB20):

Now accept the one who is weak in faith, but not to have
quarrels over opinions.

At this point in our reading, do we know who is weak and who is not?  No. So, don't read assumptions we might make in a brief moment back into this sentence.  But, we know that unity (or lack thereof) is clearly a part of what weak means.  So, we should be thinking, right at this point, that the strong are those who participate in unity.  The weak do not.
Note:  The Greek doesn't have any form of 'but'.  The second clause is  epexegetic and so basically explains the first clause.  Paul is saying that accepting the weaker should not result in judgemental disputes (μὴ εἰς διακρίσεις διαλογισμῶ). Also, I suggest that προσλαμβάνω is a bit stronger than 'accept'.  There's connotations of "take hold of."  It's not, "We love you brother, just sit in the back pew."  It's "Welcome!  You're fully part of our body."  "Fully accept" would be better, IMO.
So, how does Paul develop the definition(s) of weak and strong?  He uses the irony inherent in the situation.  The irony with the terms weak and strong is which is which, or better, who is who?
Is the person who eats the idol meat the strong one?  Or is it the one who refrains?  The true answer:  both are true depending on conscience.
Is the person who eats the idol meat the weak one?  Or is it the one who refrains?  The true answer:  both are true depending on conscience.
It's this ironic interplay that causes our own quandary with the text.
See what I mean?  It's not hard to envision a person saying, "I don't eat the meat" and thinking, "I'm the strong one."  Ditto for the opposite person.  The problem with the assumed definitions of weak and strong that people (and we're included here) naturally come up with when living out life in a body of believers is the definitions don't differentiate.  If anything, the assumed definitions tend to reinforce that it's the other guy who is the weak one.  And that's exactly contrary to the point Paul is making here.
My point is that Paul uses the terms weak and strong to zero in on the actual problem:  It's not about you.  It's about the other person.  And so, there shouldn't be this problem of διάκρισις (judicial determination) with each other that leads to διαλογισμός (disputes).
I think Paul shares two principles in Romans 14.  And I think having these two principles in mind when reading Romans 14 helps clarify what's going on.

For you as an individual: The decisions of action you make are to reflect your commitment for Christ's benefit.  If you do or you don't do something, are you doing or not doing it so as to be faithful to him?  If yes, then stand by that.  If not, then it's not that important.  Drop it and move on.
And this is not, "I do X so that I show I'm a good person," whether you're a believer or not.  It's, "I do X (or don't do X) to bring actual, realized benefit to the Lord."  God isn't interested in one's selfish obedience.  Paul explains the failure of such efforts in Romans 7 as well as denouncing it in other places.  We're to live for the Lord's benefit.



Romans 14:7-8:  For not one of us lives for himself, and not one dies for himself; for if we live, we live for the Lord, or if we die,
we die for the Lord; therefore whether we live or die, we are the Lord’s.


For the corporate body, you are not to put in place rules that entrap people who have a commitment to Christ to do or not do something.


Romans 14:13:  Therefore let’s not judge one another anymore, but rather determine this: not to put an obstacle or a stumbling block
in a brother’s or sister’s way.

The word translated stumbling block is the word entrap (σκάνδαλον).  Picture putting a rule in place that unavoidably puts a person in a Catch-22 situation.  If they do the thing, their conscience will say, "That is wrong."  If they don't do it, their conscience will say, "That is wrong."  That's what Paul is referring to by entrapping.  "Cause to stumble" is a good translation of the word translated as "put an obstacle" (πρόσκομμα).  But, "stumbling-block" is a poor translation for something that was used to ensnare.
For many of today's American Baptist churches, a good example of this entrapment would be using only wine in a communion.  What would the teetotal congregant do?  They're trapped.
So, there's a beautiful balance resting between these two rules as they interplay with each other in the daily grind of life.
Romans 14 is about the pursuit of unity within the body.  And, there are two rules:  1.  Christ gets to define what I do or don't do; his identity molds my identity.  I act "in his name, representing him"  And 2, I should not entrap others with my commitment. This is where the διάκρισις comes into play.  διάκρισις is when the determination of right and wrong seeks to force others to conform to my Christ-oriented commitments.
So, the answer to the OP question,

Is it correct that the strong brother rather than the weak brother is
the one condemned in Romans 14:23?

is, it depends.  What's the definitions of weak and strong?  Paul's definition presented here is that the strong are those who pursue unity.  So, no, it's not the strong brother.  But, if the "strong brother" is the "my way or the highway" person, then yes, that person is sinning.
[sidebar note:  I'm not using the term 'unity' in an ecumenical, lowest common denominator sense.  It's actual Biblical unity.]
The above two rules place this verse in a completely different context of interpretation.  The person who chooses to do something controversial (ie takes a stand) and does so without considering  the commitment that makes to Christ (ie. doubting) is one who fails (sins).  Or, to state it differently, does the taking a stand honestly show a commitment to who Christ is (which, because of who Christ is, shows an empathy to other people)?  There's a balance.

The weaker and the stronger are both believers (possess some amount of faith).  The weaker brother in faith is not comfortable with eating certain things, but even though they lack the level of faith that the stronger brother has (who knows he can eat whatever), they choose not to partake because of their weaker belief that it honors God to not eat.  Both believers are acting "in faith" for God either way.  One person "eats" for God, the other does not eat...for God.
Romans 14:23 KJV:

And he that doubteth is damned if he eat, because he eateth not of faith: for whatsoever is not of faith is sin.

The characteristics of the "doubter" of verse 23 are:

They possess no faith.
They are still in their sins (because they possess no faith).
They are damned (because they possess no faith).

The above traits are contrary to believers who:

Possess some amount of faith.
Are no longer in their sins.
Are not condemned for their sins.

The doubter in verse 23 is in reference to a non-believer. He "that doubteth" has zero faith.  This person eats whatever, but he is not like the stronger believer (who knows they have the liberty to eat anything).  This person eats anything but has no faith, and is therefore damned regardless.  Although they too have the ability to eat anything, it is not a sign of possessing stronger faith in this case.  They have no faith and are "damned" for that reason alone, not because they choose to eat or otherwise.
Romans 8:1

There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit.


DeGraaf is correct that the strong brother would be acting in a divisive way by eating. But Paul consistently teaches that it is the weak person who is condemned (or rather condemns himself) by eating what he thinks he must not eat.
The one who doubts is the one who does not have faith that "everything is indeed clean." (vs. 20) If he eats, he violates he conscience, which is a sin.  However, the one who is strong in faith should respect the one who is weak because "it is wrong for anyone to become a stumbling block by eating." In other words, Paul advises the spiritually mature brother not to tempt the weaker one to violate his conscience, even though his conscience is not properly educated yet. He should also make unity a higher value than personal preference in this case, so as to avoid disputes and judgmental attitudes. (vs. 1-3)
This is the same line of thought Paul pursues in dealing with the question of food sacrificed to idols.
1 Cor. 8

Now food will not bring us closer to God. We are no worse off if we do
not eat, nor are we better off if we do. 9 But make sure that this
liberty of yours in no way becomes a stumbling block to the weak... 13 Therefore, if food causes my brother to sin {because he think an idol has actual power}, I will
never eat meat again, so that I may not cause my brother to sin.

In both cases, the "weak" brother is the one who does not understand that diet is unrelated to sin. He thinks eating forbidden food is a sin and thereby condemns himself (sins against his conscience) if he eats. Meanwhile, the one who is strong in faith should respect the weaker one's situation rather than acting divisively or pushing him to disobey his conscience.
